# The Calendar Type for input it to database

Tags: c#, date, calendar

for this project i use MonthCalendar  like this:

[image]

from the toolbox in order to make this project more have variances on date time rather than i use DateTimePicker for it. For the DateTimePicker option, i use this method

`DateTime dates = dtpdate.Value;`

and then, i save the value with this LOC `newR.rentDate = dates;`

While i use MonthCalendar Option, i can't use this method because the option just have this option of autocomplete code [image: Month Calendar Auto Complete].

In this case, i use this LOC

```
newuser.DOB = caldob.DateSelected.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

but unfortunately, there is an error on the DateSelected part.
It said that

> Error 12  The event 'System.Windows.Forms.MonthCalendar.DateSelected' can only appear on the left hand side of += or -=   E:\VERSION\5.0\Agenindo\kepegawaian.cs  206 38  Agenindo

So how i can pick the date to save it in the database Which is the format is "dd/MM/yyyy". Thanks all :D

Comment: Its Event. Se documentations for events in msdn

Comment: @Ramankingdom i have read the documentation and i don't really undestand the example. hmm i'll search it immediately.

Comment: basically, it will give you a range. Means Start Date and End Date just like you see in return flight ticket booking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can subscribe to any of these events:-

```
caldob.DateSelected += new System.Windows.Forms.DateRangeEventHandler(this.caldob_DateSelected);
 
caldob.DateChanged += new System.Windows.Forms.DateRangeEventHandler(this.caldob_DateChanged);
```

**And handlers be like**

```
private void caldob_DateSelected(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.DateRangeEventArgs e)
{
      //e.Start;     //gives the start date
      //e.End ;    //gives the end date
}

private void caldob_DateChanged(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.DateRangeEventArgs e)
{
    
      //e.Start;     //gives the start date
      //e.End ;    //gives the end date
}
```

The other properties you can look for your problem are

> MaxSelectionCount :- Gets or sets the maximum number of days that can
> be selected in a month calendar control.
>
> MinDate : - Gets or sets the minimum allowable date.